# How can I define an after_add method on the relation class instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord

I have a `Character` class and a `Siblingship` class.

To denote that one character is a "sibling" of another, I save a Siblingship instance with a `character_id` (the "primary" Character being edited) and a `sibling_id` (the character being marked as a sibling to the primary character).

I would like to add functionality to automatically create a *second* Siblingship instance with the reverse IDs (so if I mark Alice as Bob's sibling, I also mark Bob as Alice's sibling).

This would be an easy `after_add` if I put the logic in the Character class:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :siblingships
  has_many :siblings, through: :siblingships, after_add: :reciprocate

  def reciprocate(sibling)
    ...
  end
end
```

However, this is a larger project with ~100 different relations like this (connecting a dozen different "content" classes, not just Characters), and storing the `after_add` (and, often, a reversed `after_remove`) on the Character model would get very unwieldy fast.

So I'd like to store the logic of "what to do when an association of this type is created" on that association, instead of the class that holds that association.

Something like:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :siblingships
  has_many :siblings, through: :siblingships, after_add: Siblingship.reciprocate
end
```

Is there a good way to do this? I've also tried specifying `reciprocate` as an instance method, like

```
has_many :siblings, through: :siblingships, after_add: Siblingship.new.reciprocate
```

But not only does it error [*wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)*] on the method, but it also feels wrong to be instantiating Siblingships here just to get to an instance method.

I would very much appreciate any solutions on how to solve this problem while keeping the Character class clean, and preferably keeping logic about each relation in that relation's class.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but keep in mind that after_add should only be passed a symbol or lamba/proc. Your `Siblingship.reciprocate` is evaluated _at the time the model class is defined_

Comment: My recommendation would be to create a "PORO" class to manage the whole thing then it can create the reciprocal relationships. The reason being is that this is not a concern of the "Siblingship" nor the "Sibling" but rather should be managed by something like a "SiblingManager"that oversees the creation of these relationships.

Comment: @engineersmnky Something like a service you'd call on containing model (Character) update instead of triggering on save callbacks? Ideally, I'd prefer not to create managers for each relationship, since there's ~100.

Comment: Also it'd be nice to have the logic on the relationship models so I don't have to check in the otherwise-restful CharactersController logic for which relations are created, removed, saved-but-unchanged, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this can be solved with simple hooks on the joining model (e.g. `Siblingship`) instead of trying to add them to the relevant class they join (e.g. `Character`).

The code's a bit abstracted out from the concrete example I gave in the question because I needed a solution that worked across unlimited joining classes with minimal code duplication. Here's what I ended up doing to get two-way linking (both on create and delete) working:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :siblingships
  has_many :siblings, through: :siblingships
end
```

And then, for each joining class:

```
class Siblingship < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SmartContentLinking
  LINK_TYPE = :two_way

  belongs_to :character
  belongs_to :sibling, class_name: 'Character'

  # Since this is a two-way relation, also create an opposite relation
  after_create do
    self.reciprocate relation: :siblingships, parent_object_ref: :character, added_object_ref: :sibling
  end

  # Since this is a two-way relation, also delete any opposite relation
  after_destroy do
    this_object  = Character.find_by(id: self.character_id)
    other_object = Character.find_by(id: self.sibling_id)

    other_object.siblings.delete this_object
  end
end
```

Obviously there are still things to pull out to make the code a lot cleaner (and entirely abstracted into the SmartContentLinking concern), but this works for now.

The SmartContentLinking concern:

```
require 'active_support/concern'
module SmartContentLinking
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # Default linking to one-way. All possible values:
  #  - :one_way
  #  - :two_way
  LINK_TYPE = :one_way

  included do
    def reciprocate relation:, parent_object_ref:, added_object_ref:
      parent_object = self.send(parent_object_ref)
      added_object  = self.send(added_object_ref)

      # if some_character.siblingships.pluck(:sibling_id).include?(parent_object.id)
      if added_object.send(relation).pluck("#{added_object_ref}_id").include?(parent_object.id)
        # Two-way relation already exists
      else
        # If a two-way relation doesn't already exist, create it
        added_object.send(relation) << relation.to_s.singularize.camelize.constantize.create({
          "#{parent_object_ref}": added_object,   # character: sibling
          "#{added_object_ref}":  parent_object   # sibling:   character
        })
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore ActiveRecord and look at what you're trying to achieve.

> When a Character has a new sibling added, the sibling's existing
>   sibling relationships needs to be realigned.

You mentioned that this is a project with ~100 similar relations. So, we might generalize the above to:

> When a new relationship is formed, existing relationships on both
>   sides need to be realigned.

I'm going to work with the first definition as I don't know the rest of your domain. You might change this example based on your better understanding of your domain.

Based on the definition, the code might look something like:

```
class Character
  def add_sibling_relationship(another_character)
    siblings.add(another_character)
    another_character.realign_sibling_relationships(self)
  end

  def realign_sibling_relationships(sibling)
    siblings.add(sibling)
  end
end
```

Everything is still in `Character`, which is going to be a problem once the relationships grow. So let's decouple the process from the ActiveRecord model.

We're talking about siblinghood here, so that's what we'll call the resulting class:

```
class Siblinghood
  def initialize(sibling_one, sibling_two)
    @sibling_one, @sibling_two = sibling_one, sibling_two
  end

  def form
    @sibling_one.siblings << @sibling_two unless @sibling_one.siblings.include?(@sibling_two)
    @sibling_two.siblings << @sibling_one unless @sibling_two.siblings.include?(@sibling_one)
  end
end
```

This changes how we create siblings. Instead of

```
@character.siblings.add(@other_character)
```

we now need to call:

```
Siblinghood.new(@character, @other_character).form
```

Let's take it a step further. If we wanted to remove this sibling relationship, where would a logical place be to put that logic?

```
Siblinghood.new(@character, @other_character).destroy
```

Now, we have somewhere to consolidate the logic of managing siblinghood. However, this means our controllers and other classes need to be aware of `Siblinghood`, which isn't necessary - no other class cares about how siblings are formed.

Let's move invocation back into `Character`.

```
class Character
  def add_sibling(other_character)
    Siblinghood.new(self, other_character).form
  end

  def remove_sibling(other_character)
    Siblinghood.new(self, other_character).destroy
  end
end
```

This gives us a nice balance - `Character` only implements as many methods as external classes need to know, and all the logic required for sibling management is tucked away neatly.